# Nested if statement in calculated list item

Tags: calculated-column

This should be easy but I have been beating my head against the wall on it.  Here is my statement I'm using:

=IF(AND([TODAY]>[Due In],[Comp Date]=""),"NO",IF(AND([TODAY]<[Due In],[Comp Date]=""),"",IF(AND([TODAY]>[Due In],[Comp Date]>[Due In]),"NO","YES")))

Basically I am checking two date fields, due date and completion date, to make sure the project has been turned in on time. Based on the return the calculated field should populate with yes, no or stay blank.  I get a syntax or function not supported error.  Any help would be greatly appriciated.

at

Answer (score 1):

Try breaking them up into individual statements first and after you have the syntax right for all 3, merge them into the nested ifs.

Also, Today in calculated columns isn't very reliable, try the solution proposed by Christophe, http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/08/14/calculated-columns-the-useless-today-trick/

Answer (score 0):

When I enter this, it doesn't like the multi-word variables.